# Mangeto shows Small Image, Thumbnail on Product View Page

Tags: magento

I am new for magento, not sure how to modify files, actually i did everything also upload multi images but extra images "thumb, Small images not showing on frontend product view page. only showing base image...

Please take a look below code and solve my problem guys why image not showing there..

```
    <?php
        if($layout=='default'){
            $mediaCol = 'col-md-4';
            $producInfoCol = 'col-md-5';
            $slideBarCol = 'col-md-3';
        }elseif($layout=='horizontal'){
            $mediaCol = 'col-md-6';
            $producInfoCol = 'col-md-6';
        }elseif($layout=='vertical'){
            $mediaCol = 'col-md-3';
            $producInfoCol = 'col-md-6';
            $slideBarCol = 'col-md-3';
        }elseif($layout=='custom1'){
            $mediaCol = 'col-md-12';
            $producInfoCol = 'col-md-12';
        }elseif($layout=='custom2'){
            $mediaCol = 'col-md-7';
            $producInfoCol = 'col-md-5';
        }
    ?>
    <div class="left-product col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="left-product-view row" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <div class="product-img-box col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $this->helper('mtfour')->getLabel($_product);  ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="product-shop col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
            <div class="top-product-name">
                    <div class="product-name col-lg-9">
                        <h1 itemprop="name" style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') . ' MOULDING'; ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-prev-next nav-wrapper col-lg-3 pull-right">
                        <ul>
                            <?php if($_prev): ?>
                                <li><a rel="prev" class="product-prev flex-prev left" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_prev->getName()); ?>" href="<?php echo $_prev->getProductUrl(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_next): ?>
                                <li><a rel="next" class="product-next flex-next right" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_next->getName()); ?>" href="<?php echo $_next->getProductUrl(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                    <div class="std" itemprop="description"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <!--<span class="or"><?php //echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>-->
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try below code to display all images of product.

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php if($_images){?>            
    <?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(108,90); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /><?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```